# Skobbler SKMapView and UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, skmaps

I've got a question about Skobbler MapView and `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. It seems that `UIPanGestureRecognizer` intercepts all pan events from `SKMapView` and blocks from moving map position.

You could see code example below, the only difference between my application that UIPanGestureRecognizer is located in parent view 2 levels above.

```
import UIKit

class IPSkobblerViewController : UIViewController {

    var mapView : SKMapView!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        mapView = SKMapView();
        mapView.exclusiveTouch = true;
        self.view.addSubview(mapView);

        let gestureRecogniser = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panGesture");
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecogniser);

    }

    func panGesture() {
        NSLog("Pan Gesture");
    }

}
```

Comment: We're looking into it

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is set the recogniser's cancelsTouchesInView to false

```
gestureRecogniser.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

This will enable the gesture recogniser to allow the view it is attached to, to receive touch events. If that view is not the map view, then the touch events have to be forwarded to it.

Comment: I'm having kind of the same problem. I have the map embedded into a UICollectionViewCell, so the pan gesture of the collection view is called WITH the map's pan gesture (this is when the cancelsTouchesInView is false). I can't seem to find any way around it because there is no reference to any of the gestures of the SKMapView. The pan gesture on the SKMapView should just require collection view's gesture to fail. I also tried to CancelContentTouches on the UICollectionView but that made it not respond to any touches (of course), which is not what I want. Will appreciate feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will be fixed in the 3.0.2 release.